# Make Content appear without refresh

Tags: jquery, joomla, refresh

Jquery 1.6.1.
Joomla 1.5.

I have created a template witch will
animate headers height and fadein headers content.

At the same time content area is hidden.
What i want to do is : somehow make content Div appear when i click a menu option from header and stay there untill i click a close button.

I cant figure out how to "bypass" the page's refresh problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, assuming the buttons have an id '#id' and content has '#idContent'  otherwise just change the naming convention to work with it.

```
 $.bind('click', function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('activeButton'))
        {
             $(this+'Content').css('display','none');
             $(this).removeClass('activeButton');
        }
        else
        {
               $(this+'Content').css('display','block');
               $(this).addClass('activeButton');
        }
    });
```

This is just an example.  You can always change it around to customize your size, but that is the idea.

Sometimes i need to use 'visibility','visible'/'hidden'(instead of display block).  It depends; try both.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could go to "http://jquery.com/", and then click "Run code" on the example : it makes a div appear with content.